# Replace contents of a script block using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I've a script block in HTML which basically has some JSON content. I would like to replace contents inside it using jQuery. I did something like this:

```
$("#data").html(newjson);
```

Above statement only works with Firefox. It does not work with IE? How do I make this work in IE.

Comment: can you copy the string **newjson** and post it here?

Comment: pardon me, but what difference does it make?

Comment: It makes a difference, because .html() works fine in all modern browsers. I presume it's got something to do with the code you're adding.

Comment: What do you mean does not work. Did you get an error, did js execution stopped, etc?

Answer (score 1):

Have a try removing the script element and adding a new one with your new json.